# VBA. Access to an array element of the Variant. An array is a class property

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class with an ArrSignalCabel variable. In this variable I write an array of objects.
Property Get bottom of my class returns only an array. And I do not have access to the array element.

```
 Option Explicit
Private ArrSignalCabel As Variant

Property Let ArrSignalCab(ByVal ArrValue As Variant)
 ArrSignalCabel = ArrValue
End Property

Property Get ArrSignalCab() As Variant
 ArrSignalCab = ArrSignalCabel
End Property

Public Property Get ArrSignalCabIn(index As Integer) As Variant ' not work
 ArrSignalCabIn(index) = ArrSignalCabel(index)
End Property
```

////////////////

```
NameObjTM2 = TempPanel.ArrCabelPan(i).ArrSignalCabIn(0) ' not work
NameObjTM3 = TempPanel.ArrCabelPan(i).ArrSignalCab      ' work
NameObjTM4=  NameObjTM3(0).NameSig                      ' work
```

PS:
TempPanel - an object that contains an array of objects(ArrCabelPan).
ArrCabelPan - the class structure is identical to that described.

Comment: no error( 'NameObjTM2 = TempPanel.ArrCabelPan(i).ArrSignalCabIn(0)' value is 'Nothing'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ArrSignalCabIn = ArrSignalCabel(index)`?

The name of the property should match what you declared in the `Property Get`, like `Function`.

Comment: So tried. The problem is that 'Public Property Get ArrSignalCabIn' VBA do not see.I think I have to add more 'Public Property Let/(Set) ArrSignalCabIn' but I do not know how correct

Comment: try `Private ArrSignalCabel() As Variant` to declare it as Array of Variants.

Comment: not work. I get error. https://drive.google.com/open?id=18qx_RcG90PJzuXUHIGRrLd85_DFyyLtb

Answer (score 0):

I find answer

```
Public Property Get ArrSignalCabIn(Index As Integer) As Variant
If (ArrSignalCabel(Index) Is Nothing) Then Set ArrSignalCabel(Index) = New Signal
Set ArrSignalCabIn = ArrSignalCabel(Index)
End Property
```

Thanks to those who helped